# FlashDevelop receives XML, Flash Pro receives JSON

Tags: json, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm getting a data feed from a client's supplier. 
Documention says that I can get the feed both in XML and in JSON, but that the default is XML. To get JSON I have to set a header **Accept:application/json** and remove **Accept:application/xml** header.
I have not set nor removed any headers in my code. 
I'm using a normal URLLoader to load the feed.

When I navigate to the feed url in a browser, I get **XML**.
When I run my code in FlashDevelop, I get **XML**.
When I run the exact same code in Flash Pro, I get **JSON**.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this in Flash Pro? Any hidden setting that can be changed?
URLRequest.method has no impact. Debug mode or not has no impact.
I'm stomped.

---------code I tried------------

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
var headers:Array = [];
headers.push(header);
urlReq.requestHeaders = headers;
urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

--------- full load code -----------

```
_urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, validateFeedLoaded);
_urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleFeedIOerror);
_urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleFeedSecError);
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_feedUrl);
urlReq.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")];
_urlLoader.load(urlReq);
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like sniffing the headers of the requests your various clients send?

Comment: The clients aren't involved at this stage, I'm still building this data feed. But if i check the urlrequest.requestHeaders in my code i get nothing.

Comment: Of course they are involved, you are asking why 3 different clients receive different results. As @Marc B suggested, monitor the HTTP communication to see if the requests made are different.

Comment: browser = client 1. flashdevel = client 2, flashpro = client 3. make SURE that the headers you're sending aren't being overiden/replaced.

Comment: Client != company customer  x)
Okay well I'm the first to admit I'm far from a header savant.
My knowledge on this stretches to checking urlReg.requestHeaders in my code and I got an empty value when tracing that, no matter if I'm in FD or Flash Pro.
Any ideas how I can get more info on this? I have no controll over the server where there url we load is "located".

Comment: Show your current code for loading the data.

Comment: Also, might be helpful to know what version of Flash Pro you are using?  Is the data source public (something you can share?)   I'd like to try and reproduce this.

Comment: The Flash Pro version is Animate CC 2015.2. The data source is not public from what I know I'm sorry to say. In the browser it shows the data source as XML as I've mentioned and the root node includes  <somename xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PartnerAPI.DataAccess.Models"> Have updated my question with my loading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different clients/applications have different defaults.  Different versions of the flash/air runtime may have different defaults for the accept type.

If you need consistency, then you should explicitly set the accept type in your request:

```
urlrequest.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")];
```

This should ensure you get JSON back in both IDE's in whatever version of the runtime you're using.

Comment: It works in FlashDevelop, thanks. It just does NOT work in Flash Pro. In FlashDevelop i can set the header to either JSON or XML and it works perfectly, but in Flash Pro the header i set with the code has no impact at all.